# `export default let foo = ...` throws "Unexpected strict mode reserved word"

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

I'm trying out JavaScript modules by enabling the "Experimental Web Platform" flag in Chrome Dev (v60, at time of writing).

When I try to import this module:

```
export default let foo = 10;
```

I get this error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
```

It works fine without the `default` keyword. And this works fine too:

```
let a = 10;
export default a;
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) doesn't explicitly say that the `export default ...` notation is allowed with `let`, `var`, `const`, etc. but they do give examples with functions like this:

```
export default function (…) { … }.
```

And variables like this:

```
export let name1 = …, name2 = …, …, nameN;
```

**Question:** Is it not possible with the current specification to export regular variables with the `default` keyword as can be done with functions and classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`export` has [strictly defined syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Syntax), the proper syntax for default export is

```
export default expression;
```

`let foo = 10` is not an expression but a statement. It can be used for named exports:

```
export let name1, name2, …, nameN;
```

For default export name is not needed.

Similarly to `export default function (…) { … }`, it should be

```
export default 10;
```

Comment: Ahh I see, didn't know I could just do `export default 10;`! But why do they have this example in [the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)?
 `export let name1 = …, name2 = …, …, nameN;`

Comment: As the answer says, It is for *named exports*, not for *default* (`default` is actually the name).

Comment: Also, it is not actually 'variables vs classes/functions' exports. `class Foo {...}` is a statement, so it can be named export, `export class Foo {...}`,. But it can also be an expression, both `export default class Foo {...}` and `export default class {...}` are ok. The same applies to functions. `var/let/const` statements aren't expressions. You can't use them anywhere where an expression is expected. Try something like `return let foo = 10` and you will get syntax error, too.

Comment: Ah so a function definition like `function foo() {...}` can be both an expression and a statement. The `return let foo = 10` analogy is great 